# Is it possible to move MBR from one HDD to another?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, mbr

I have two HDD, when I installed Ubuntu its MBR went to the first HDD. In the second HDD Windows XP was installed. When I boot system it automatically goes to XP unless I change HDD manually to see Grub Loader menu and go to ubuntu.

Can I change the MBR to something that I can see Grub Loader. To move MBR from the first HDD to the second one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change the MBR, if you have two physical hard disks, change their Boot Order in the BIOS so that the Grub Disk boots first.